# Is there a scalar type for arrays and maps in graphql for schemas in AWS amplify?

Tags: graphql, aws-amplify

I was learning to use AWS amplify with React, and the API it uses is a GraphQL API that leverages AWS AppSync. I'm very new to graphQL and my schema currently is like this. This is the schema inside the amplify app:

```
type Note @model {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  description: String
  title: String
  image: String
}
```

To give you an example, I want to store an array of objects inside components in the Note type like this:

**Code-1**

```
type Note @model {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  description: String
  title: String
  image: String
  components: []
}
```

But reading the docs I got to know there aren't any array scalar types. I know that I can create another table and do it like this instead:

**Code-2**

```
 type Note @model {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  description: String
  title: String
  image: String
  components: [elements!]!
}
 
 type elements @model {
  id: ID!
  item: String!
}
```

But I don't want this as it creates a new table. I just want one table containing id, name, description, title, image and a components array where you can store objects in like shown above in **Code-1**. Is there any possible way to do this? Also whats the role of "@modal" in the schema?

Comment: "custom JSON scalar" - check general graphql and amplify docs

Comment: @xadm Thank you so much. Figured out "AWSJSON" can be used, I guess my mistake was looking at the graphql docs instead of the AWS docs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Checked out the AWS docs and found out that I could use AWSJSON for lists/arrays like [1, 2, 3] and maps like {"upvotes": 10}, so now my schema is:

```
type Note @model {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  description: String
  title: String
  image: String
  components: AWSJSON
}
```

Here is the link to know more about it [AWS Scalar Types](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/scalars.html#example-schema-usage)

Comment: Hi Shiraaz, I got this. What do you think is the issue?

"Variable 'countriesOfDegrees' has an invalid value. Unable to parse [Albania, Antigua and Barbuda] as valid JSON."

Comment: Would need more context on the code.